# Access S3 private asset

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am simply trying to access files in my own bucket and for some reason I cannot.

**CORS**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

**Policy**

None

**User Policies**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt14973834050",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name"
            ]
        }
    ]
}

{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am able to upload files, but cannot fetch anything which seems like it should be easier.  Am I missing something obvious?

When I attempt to fetch an asset.  I get a `403 Forbidden` response.

Comment: What do you have on the Permissions tab (the one where you assign Read/Write permissions on a per-user basis)?  Also how are you accessing the bucket? If you are using the CLI then I think CORS is out of the picture.

Comment: I'm now trying to make it work via presigned urls as this isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

Some Amazon S3 policies operate at the **bucket level** (`"arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name"`) and some operate at the **object level** (`"arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*"`).

Bucket-level operations including listing buckets and uploading to buckets. Object-level operations include downloading objects.

To give a user all Amazon S3 permissions on a particular bucket, use a policy like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowAllOnBucket",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```